# Redis get member where score is between min and max

Tags: redis

I have a table in sql with 3 columns: `BIGINT StartNumber, BIGINT EndNumber, BIGINT LocationId`, and I need to be able to do something like this

```
Select LocationId where StartNumber < @number and EndNumber > @number.
```

for example:

```
StartNumber EndNumber LocationId
1             5          1
6             9          1
10            16         2
```

and when I have @number = 7 I should get LocationId = 1

How can I do this in redis?

I was thinking to move this table to redis, use sorted set and `ZRANGEBYSCORE` but it did't work for me:
1) When I am using ZADD key score member [score] [member], I am unable to add 2 elements with the same member and different score even with nx parameter:
`zadd myset nx 1 "17" 2 "17"` - it will add one element and then update its score instead of adding two elements.
2) when I am adding this: `zadd set1 2 "a" 4 "b" 6 "c" 10 "d"` and then trying to do zrangebyscore set1 3 3 (want to get member whose score include 3) I em getting empty result

P.s. All commands are executed on the example pages of redis website.

Comment: And what's the purpose of adding a member twice or more with different scores?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer in sql I have a range of numbers related to location id, like numbers from 1 to 5 are related to locationid = 1 and as sorted set can have only 2 columns for each element (score-member) I suppose, I need to add to elements for each row from sql table, like StartIp - Location and EndIp - Location. Or I should create 2 sorted sets like suggested bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I understood the task, you don't have overlaps and each interval maps to only one location (?) and intervals don't have gaps. Based on this you can use only one sorted list with lower (or upper) bound values:

```
ZADD StartNumber 1 "1:5:1" 6 "6:9:1" 10 "10:16:2"
```

Then you can use:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE StartNumber 7 -inf LIMIT 0 1
```

And it will be O(log(N)).

Comment: I agree - that's what I came to realize too :)

Answer (score 2):

Put differently, your question is "how can I map N ranges of numbers to a location". One way of doing this is using two Sorted Sets, one for the `StartNumber` and the other one for `EndNumber`. Since members have to be unique, we'll also need to ensure that by using the Start/End values as part of the member. For example, with your example data, this could be done like so:

```
ZADD StartNumber 1 "1:5:1" 6 "6:9:1" 10 "10:16:2"
ZADD EndNumber 5 "1:5:1" 9 "6:9:1" 16 "10:16:2"
```

To find the location for @number=7, do `ZRANGEBYSCORE StartNumber -inf 7` and `ZRANGEBYSCORE EndNumber 7 +inf` and intersect the results. All that remains is to split the intesect's result(s) on the colon (`:`) and use the 3rd element as the location.

**Note**: if your app ensures that there are no overlapping ranges and that there can be only one location per "number", you can get the same results with only one set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I understand correctly that if I have 5 million records and `@number` is somewhere in the middle (or this even don't matter) `ZRANGEBYSCORE StartNumber -inf @number` and `ZRANGEBYSCORE EndNumber @number +inf` will return all 5 million records and I will need to intersect them on website's server side without usage of any additional Redis commands?

Comment: You could do everything Redis-side with a Lua script, but client-side (i.e. website server) is also a valid approach. However, if you actually have 5M such values, you may want to consider a different approach regardless where the intersect is taking place... How many values, locations and number ranges do you need to manage?

Comment: There is about 5M records in this table, each record has 3 bigint columns - StartNumber, EndNumber and LocationId. LocationIds are repeated as some location can have several ranges of numbers assigned to it.

Comment: Hmm. So I'm assuming that ranges don't overlap (i.e. up to a single location per any given bigint). What about operations besides this query - is the data updated heavily and/or are there other types of reads? I have may have an idea or two

Comment: Oh, and about these start and end numbers - are you actually using the full bigint space (assuming -2^63..2^63) for these ranges?

Comment: Yes, ranges don't overlap. This table is updated very rarely (once in several weeks/months) and no other operations - it is only used to get LocationId by understanding to what range @number belong to. re: Bigint - now not all range is used, max number is 3758096383

Answer (score 1):

(this is the first time that I'm giving two answers to the same question - maybe I'll get a badge or sumthin' ;))

The double Sorted Set approach is a generalization and, as such, aims to solve a bigger set of problems than what the OP needs (as put in the comments to the first answer). That approach is also not effective as the query is O(logn)+O(N) so when N is large (e.g. 5M) that's probably not a good idea.

However, to satisfy the requirements and given that the ranges do not overlap, one could actually use only a single Sorted Set and a simpler query. The set's members should be added by concatenating the `EndNumber` and `LocationId` and the their scores should be set to their respective `StartNumber`, so for the sake of the example:

```
ZADD ranges 1 "5:1" 6 "9:1" 10 "16:2"
```

Given @number, obtain the relevant `LocationId` with the following Redis Lua code (O(logn)):

```
-- rangelookup.lua
-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185898/redis-get-member-where-score-is-between-min-and-max/32186675
-- A **non inclusive** range search on a Sorted Set with the following data:
--   score = <StartNumber>
--   member = <EndNumber>:<LocationId>
--
-- KEYS[1] - Sorted Set key name
-- ARGV[1] - the number to search
--
-- reply - the relevant id, nil if range doesn't exist
-- 
-- usage example: redis-cli --eval rangelookup.lua ranges , 7

local number = tonumber(ARGV[1])
local data = redis.call('ZREVRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], number, '-inf', 'WITHSCORES', 'LIMIT', 0, 1)
local reply = nil

if data ~= nil and number > tonumber(data[2]) then
  local to, id = data[1]:match( '(.*):(.*)' )
  if tonumber(to) > number then
    reply = id
  end
end

return reply
```

Sample output:

```
$ redis-cli --eval rangelookup.lua ranges , 7
"1"
$ redis-cli --eval rangelookup.lua ranges , 9
(nil)
$ redis-cli --eval rangelookup.lua ranges , 99
(nil)
```